# Prove that the gradient of a 2 variable function behave like a vector under 2-D rotations.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Function $f$ has two variables ($y$ and $z$). Show that $\displaystyle \nabla f = {\partial f \over \partial y}\ \hat j \ + \ {\partial f \over \partial z} \ \hat k$ transforms as a vector under rotations. 
>   Hint : use $${\partial f\over \partial \overline y} = {\partial f\over \partial y} { \partial y\over\partial \overline  y} + {\partial f\over \partial z} { \partial z\over\partial \overline  y} \tag{+} $$
>   and analogous of this for $\displaystyle {\partial f\over \partial \overline z}$

---

I think I have done this correctly but please check my solution.

I know $\overline y = y\cos \theta + z \sin \theta$ and $\overline z = -y\sin \theta + z\cos \theta$

I solved for $y$ and $z$ as a function of $\overline y$ and $\overline z$.

I got $y = \overline y \cos \theta - \overline z \sin \theta$ and $z = \overline y  \sin \theta + \overline z \cos \theta$

Now, as per the hint I calculated

$${ \partial y\over\partial \overline  y}  = \cos \theta\ \ \& \ \ { \partial z\over\partial \overline  y} = \sin\theta$$

From this and $(+)$ I got, 
$${\partial f\over \partial \overline y} = {\partial f\over \partial y} \cos \theta + {\partial f\over \partial z} \sin\theta $$

Similarly I got,

$${\partial f\over \partial \overline z} = {\partial f\over \partial z} \cos \theta - { \partial y\over\partial \overline  z}\sin\theta$$

So now I think transformed gradient would be

$$\overline\nabla f =\left({\partial f\over \partial y} \cos \theta + {\partial f\over \partial z} \sin\theta,{\partial f\over \partial z} \cos \theta - { \partial y\over\partial \overline  z}\sin\theta\right) $$

Which is similar to a vector. Hence done.

---

- I can't seems to visualise this question. Please provide some intuitive insight on this question ?
- Where does we get $(+)$ ?
- Is this correct ?

Comment: Equation $(+)$ is just the chain rule.

Comment: Multivariate chain rule ? I don't get the second term on the RHS.

Comment: $f$ *is* a  multivariable function, so yes.

Comment: Please can you show me that part please ?